# Can't stop family link supervision on Xiaomi

Tags: android-12, google-family-link

I followed the stop supervision from [this](https://support.google.com/families/answer/9055704?hl=en)

1. On parent device in Family link the advice is:

> On your parent device, open Family Link . Select the child who will no
> longer be supervised. Tap Manage Settings  Account Info  Stop
> supervision.

but there is no stop supervision there. Just "delete account and data"

---

2. On child's device the suggestion is:

> On your child's device, open Settings . On Android versions 8.1 (O)
> and later, tap Digital Wellbeing & parental controls. On other Android
> versions, tap Google  Parental controls. At the top right, tap More
> Stop supervision.

it waits for 5 minutes, then says "Unexpected error occurred"

Also I changed his birth year from 2005 to 2015 not knowing I won't be able to undo it. My other son however was able to remove his supervision from his phone, there was no error and anything.

---

The Device: Xiaomi Redmi Note 10
Android Version: 12
MIUI Version: 14